# Select querybuilder for cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to get a few columns from cassandra table with just one column as Json string using datastax queryBuilder. I tried to construct the query in folloing ways and didnt work.

`Select.Where selectByKey = QueryBuilder.select().fcall("fromJson", "columnX")
                        .column("columnX")
                        .from("keyspaceName", "tableName")
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(key, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));`

`Select.Where selectByKey = QueryBuilder.select().fcall("fromJson", "columnX")
                        .all()
                        .from("keyspaceName", "tableName")
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(key, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));`

`Select.Where selectByKey = QueryBuilder.select().fcall("fromJson", "columnX")
                        .column("[json]")
                        .from("keyspaceName", "tableName")
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(key, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));`

Errors are like, no viable alternative at input 'columnX' (SELECT "[json]",fromJson[(]'columnX...)

All the columns are basically text except columnX which has a text in a Json format. I need some solution to get a single column as json, or whole record as json using Query Builder. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Selection.html#fcall-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), you need to use, `QueryBuilder.column("columnX")` instead of `"columnX"` as a parameter to `fcall`.

Hope it helps!